# Where should I put the gtk.h file?

Tags: c, gtk

all. I downloaded a simple GTK+ source code, :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

When I run it,

```
gcc -o simple simple.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
-bash: pkg-config: command not found
simple.c:1:21: error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
simple.c: In function ‘main’:
simple.c:5: error: ‘GtkWidget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
simple.c:5: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
simple.c:5: error: for each function it appears in.)
simple.c:5: error: ‘window’ undeclared (first use in this function)
simple.c:9: error: ‘GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

It show me the gtk.h is missing. But how can I get the gtk.h?? How can I let the programme run? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need headers and include libraries for GTK. Most distributions ship them. For example, on Debian systems, they are available as the package `libgtk2.0-dev`, so

```
 apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Install `pkg-config` in order to use it, eg. on Debian: `apt-get install pkg-config`